# Allow selection only for group child elements ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am interested in disabling row selection in `ag-grid` but only for the rows that are used to group the grid. In the picture below, clicking on the rows containing *"United States"* and *"2008"* should not be possible. Selection should be allowed only for rows like the one marked with blue. How can this be achieved? Can this be done by setting some of the grid options properties? Or do I have to use the grid events somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a callback, that will return `true` for non group rows:

```
checkboxSelection: ({node}) => !node.group
```

Here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/EsgeCFGPKynE4Ruk?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: In the example, the user can still click on the grouped row, it is colored like it selected which is confusing to the user, since only the rows below the group rows have check-boxes for selection.